# Ошибка /N в адресе файла

Tags: python, python-3.x

При запуске файла таким образом:

```
import os
    os.startfile('C:\Python27\BUY\Nine.py',)
```

Выдает ошибку что он не может нормально работать (я утрирую) из-за "/N", как оказалось что речь идет про "/Nine.py", а точнее начало слова "Nine". Но почему питон обращает на это внимание я так и не понял. 
Как это можно избежать или всегда придется назвать файл без "N"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте `r` перед строкой.

```py
import os
os.startfile(r'C:\Python27\BUY\Nine.py',)
```

---

Ошибка у Вас из-за того, что интерпретатор интерпретирует последовательность символов `\N` как какой-то **один** спецсимвол, а не как 2 разных символа. Если бы у Вас в пути встретилась последовательность символов `\n`, то это интерпретировалось бы как перенос строки. Думаю, понятно объяснил.
Буква `r` перед строкой обозначает `raw`, т.е. воспринимать строку "как есть" (интерпретировать символы `\` как полноценные символы, а не как часть спецсимволов).